How to solve menu wordpress
The menu I created had peramlinks and I change it to postname but now every page show different menu everytime. How do I solve it?
I deleted the menu and recreated it but it's the same everytime shows different menu in different pages.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
